# Conditional expression in JavaScript affected by parentheses

Tags: javascript

I came across this statement in a book and I haven't found out an explanation yet.

```
function foo() { return false }

alert(foo() == !foo); //message box says TRUE
alert(foo() == !foo()); //message box says FALSE
```

I've been thinking that the first alert would says FALSE. But it says TRUE (?)

You can see that the parentheses in the last statement make the expression return FALSE. Please tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: The key here is to notice that, in your first `alert`, it is evaluating `!foo` as opposed to `!foo()`. The former (without `( )`) is referring to the function variable itself, while the second (with `( )`) refers to the evaluated return value of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In the first case:**

```
foo() == !foo
```

LHS is `foo()` - which returns `false`

RHS is `!foo` - and since `foo` exists (and is not falsy), `!foo` is like `!true` and evaluates to `false`

Hence `foo() == !foo` is `true`

---

**In the second case:**

```
foo() == !foo()
```

LHS is `foo()` which is `false` as we know

RHS is `!foo()` - which is eual to saying `!false`, i.e. `true`

Hence `foo() == !foo()` is `false`

Answer (score 4):

`foo` is a function and therefore it is not `false`

```
function foo() { return false; };
alert(typeof foo); // function
alert(typeof foo()); // boolean
alert(!function (){}); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

The `!` operator converts the value to a boolean, then inverts it.  Function variables are `TRUE` when converted to booleans.

So, `!foo` is `!TRUE`, which is `FALSE`.  `foo()` returns `FALSE`, so `foo() == !foo`.

`foo()` returns `FALSE`, and `!foo()` is `TRUE`, since it's negating the return value.  So, `foo()` is not equal to `!foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, `foo` is not a call of the function `foo`, but is the function itself and since the function is defined it is equivalent `true` (but not really `true`). When you invert (`!`) it, it becomes `false`. Comparing it with `foo()` (which returns `false`) yields to `true` since `false == false` is `true`.

For the second one, `foo()` is now a function call of the function `foo`, which in turn returns `false`. Inverting it makes it `true`, and comparing it to another `foo()` call (which is `false`) yields to `false`, since `false == true` is `false`.